# svg text wont transform in webkit browsers

Tags: svg, webkit, transform

I'm working with an `SVG` file and some `CSS3` transform, but I'm getting troubles with `WebKit`.

I can't understand why, but it works in `Firefox`, but not with the WebKit-based browsers.

`-webkit-transform: rotate( 90deg );`

On hover in Firefox, the text rotates, but in chrome it doesn't.

Here is my example code: (http://jsfiddle.net/DcjYG/);

Comment: Given that this is SVG text, you'll likely have more luck if you use the SVG transform attribute rather than a CSS style.

Comment: You absolutely right but i have to rotete an element around the Y axis (roteteY).
As i know there is no way to do that with svg transform :(

Comment: You mean you want it to display right to left? i.e. like txet etator but with the letters backwards too?

Comment: nope i just want to rotate the text as a flag aroudn the Y axis as this : http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-OBjCZEXd7yQ/UqMhqD_XZiI/AAAAAAAAAa4/BfPF3sptKlM/s1600/rotate-y-css3.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this what you want?

```
<animateTransform type="scale" attributeName="transform" values="1,1;0,1;1, 1" begin="mouseover" dur="800ms">
```

Comment: I've updated it so it goes in and out again. Is this closer? If not what more are you looking for. "It's not working" is not very clear.

Comment: i've tryed the code and it actually works :http://jsfiddle.net/DcjYG/2/ is there a way to use the persepctive and perspective origin as i was using with css?

Comment: That's why i was using css3, anyway i got this workign with some g :http://jsfiddle.net/DcjYG/3/ problem is that the perspective works only on FF :(